# Unable to lookup a date using vba vlookup

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I have an excel worksheet with column A containing dates and column B containing the respective days.
Eg. A2=01/01/14 and B2=Wed and so on.

Im trying to retrieve the days in B2 with a sample vba code, but I keep getting an error that 
"**Run-time error '1004'
unable to get the Vlookup property of the worksheetFunction class**"

Pls see my code and advise what is wrong. Thanks.

```
 Sub Button1_Click()


Dim lookup_value As String
Dim lookup_table As Range

Let lookup_value = "1/1/2014"
Set lookup_table = Range("A:B")

the_day = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CDate(lookup_value), lookup_table, 2, False)


Range("D7") = the_day

End Sub
```

Pls note that I want to pass lookup_value manually rather than looking up cell A2.

Comment: I am pretty sure that message is happening because the VLookup function isn't finding anything.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

VLookup is sensitive to data types.  And your VBA routine is looking for a DATE data type, but such does not exist on an Excel worksheet.  So you need to convert your string lookup_value to a data type compatible with what is on the worksheet.  This could be a Long (for whole dates) or Double (if you are including times.

Try:

```
the_day = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(CDate(lookup_value)), lookup_table, 2, False)
```

Comment: This is a one-stop place for solution! Thanks so much. it works. Appreciate your help.

Comment: It's ridiculous that Excel doesn't work with VBA's DATE type. One of many Excel quirks that Microsoft should fix. I wasted a couple of hours on this until I found your answer. Thanks!