# Using VLOOKUP() in VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

We have a short table  in a worksheet like:

[image]

The values in **A1** through **A3** are are the result of these formulas:

```
=DATE(1999,12,15)
=DATE(1945,1,18)
=DATE(2020,2,23)
```

If I try to use *VLOOKUP()* in a worksheet cell:

```
=VLOOKUP(DATE(1945,1,18),A1:B3,2)
```

I get the correct result *(Moe)*:

[image]

However in VBA:

```
Sub RetrieveName()
    Dim d As Date, nam As String, rng As Range
    d = DateSerial(1945, 1, 18)
    Set rng = Range("A1:B3")
    nam = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(d, rng, 2)
    MsgBox nam
End Sub
```

I get an error:

[image]

Our current workaround is to use:

```
Sub RetrieveName2()
    Dim d As Long, nam As String, rng As Range
    d = 16455
    Set rng = Range("A1:B3")
    nam = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(d, rng, 2)
    MsgBox nam
End Sub
```

For the life of me, I can't see what is wrong with the original code ?

Comment: Declare d as double and use `cdbl(dateserial(1945,1,18))`. not sure why, but I think that vba sees the date as a string and the value coming in is a number from the worksheet.

Comment: @ScottCraner  You are correct....both `Double` and `Long` work work..........I just don't know why the conversion is necessary??

Comment: Or you could leave d as Date but use cDbl(d) in the call to VLOOKUP. I suspect the reason is that Excel is trying to convert the date variable to an Excel date, which is not a native data excel data type but a double accompanied by formatting instructions: if you pass d as a date directly to a range using Range.Value it passes the value as a number and formats it as a date. If you use Range.Value2 it appears in excel as a number without the date formatting.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams  Thank you............would `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match()` have the same limitations??

Comment: I expect so. Basically I think the problem is an incompatibility between VBA and Excel that got papered over by attempting the conversion using Range.value and making Range.value the default for both read from Excel and write to Excel.

Comment: If you define d as a variant and then retrieve it from the worksheet using d=Range("a2") - which defaults to .Value - the VLOOKUP fails: another reason to always use .Value2!

Comment: @CharlesWilliams  Could you post some suggested code...then I can close this out...

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961614/unable-to-lookup-a-date-using-vba-vlookup

Comment: @TomSharpe  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scott Craner is correct that converting the VBA Date to a Double before passing it to VLOOKUP will work.
I think the problem is that Excel and VBA are using the Range.Value rules to pass the value back to the VLOOKUP function. Excel does not have a true Date data type - dates in Excel are doubles accompanied by a date format.
Range.Value attempts to convert Excel numbers formatted as dates to VBA Dates, and vice versa when passing a VBA date back to Excel, but VLOOKUP does not understand numbers accompanied by format codes.

```
Sub RetrieveName()
    Dim d As Double, nam As Variant, rng As Range
    d = DateSerial(1945, 1, 18)
    Set rng = Range("A1:B3")
    nam = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(d, rng, 2)
    MsgBox nam
End Sub

Sub RetrieveName2()
    Dim d As Variant, nam As Variant, rng As Range
    '
    ' note Range("a2").value will fail
    '
    d = Range("a2").Value2
    Set rng = Range("A1:B3")
    nam = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(d, rng, 2)
    MsgBox nam
End Sub
```